# Incorrect data being sent to views.py from javascript in a django website

Tags: javascript, django

I am working on a basic django ecom. website. I have come across a problem which I am not able to solve. The problem is that on the products page of my website every product has a select box for size of the item and every select box has the same id (As i am iterating over the products). So whenever I choose a size for any product other than the first product the size selected from the first select box under first product goes to my database instead of the size selected under that product.
This is my html:

```
{% if product.id in list_cart %}
<div class="btn-group" style="display: none;">
<select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}} style="border: cadetblue;"
 name="size" required id="sizebox">
 {% for t in product.size.all %}
<option value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
 {% endfor %}
  </select>
  </div>
    {% else %}
 <div class="btn-group">
 <select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}} style="border: cadetblue;"
    name="size" required id="sizebox">
 {% for t in product.size.all %}
 <option value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i=0;i<updateBtns.length;i++){
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var productId=this.dataset.product
    var action=this.dataset.action


    var sizebox = document.getElementById("sizebox");
    var size = sizebox.options[sizebox.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(size)


    updateUserOrder(productId, action, size)
   
})
}
```

I want to figure out a way so that the size from the select box under a product is sent to the database instead of the size from first select box with id selectbox which is currently happening. Please help. Thanks.